# Spotify App API: Play specific track from an album

Tags: javascript, spotify

I've followed the accepted answer from this question: [Spotify App API: Play specific track from album](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416256/spotify-app-api-play-specific-track-from-album)

However, it doesn't work for me. Spotify is still playing the first track from the album.

I've had a look at view.js and I can see why it's playing the first track:

```
if (play) {
    if (m.player.context !== this._context.uri) {
      m.player.play(this._context.get(0), this._context);
    }
```

My code is below, any thoughts/suggestions?

```
var track = models.Track.fromURI(item.SpotifyUrl, function(track) { 
    var album = models.Album.fromURI(track.album.uri, function(album) {
        var trackPlayer = new views.Player();
        var t = album.data.tracks[track.data.trackNumber-1];
        trackPlayer.track = t;      
        album.get = function() {
            console.log(track.name); // I know this is being called
            return track;
        }           
        trackPlayer.context = album;
        var $player = $(trackPlayer.node);
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I had a further look at the api and within models.js I found this:

```
if (index === -1) {
...
    else if (context instanceof Album) {
        numTracks = context.tracks.length;
        while (i < numTracks) {
            if (context.tracks[i].data.availableForPlayback) {
                track = context.tracks[i];
                index = i;
                break;
            } else {
                i++;
        }
```

The following method call:

```
if (play) {
    if (m.player.context !== this._context.uri) {
      m.player.play(this._context.get(0), this._context);
    }
```

omits the 'index' parameter. Therefore the player will always play the first available track! To get around this I've added the following:

```
models.player.play = function(track, opt_context, opt_index) {
    return this.playTrackWithContext(track,opt_context,track.data.trackNumber-1);
};
```

It seems a bit of a messy workaround but until Spotify update their code it looks like the only way to get around it. Unless, I've completely missed something and there is an easier way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spotify Apps API: any more documentation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353471/spotify-apps-api-any-more-documentation)